# How to compare column in csv file using python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a csv file which contain data of professionals in LinkedIn. I wanted to analyze the data based on three columns which are job, past job and current job. The main purpose of doing this is to find out the similarity of the professionals by comparing their job / past job / current job. So how can I compare the columns in a csv file using python?

This is what I've tried

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
import re 
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 
%matplotlib inline 
dataset = pd.read_csv('modified_data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

for x in dataset['JOB']:
  for y in dataset['JOB']:
    if x == y:
        print dataset['ID']
```

This is what my dataset looks like:
 ID,NAME,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,JOB,PAST_JOB,CURRENT_JOB,LOCATION,URL

Comment: Give some more details. Your file starting rows, and your complete code including the part where you create your dataset from reading file.

Comment: I have given the details @HamzaKhurshid

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all the records in a loop, and check if they are equal.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
import re 
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") 
%matplotlib inline 
dataset = pd.read_csv('modified_data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')

for x in range(len(dataset['JOB'])): #iteration over all the records
    if dataset['JOB'][x]==dataset['PAST_JOB'][x]:
        print('ID: '+str(dataset['ID'][x])+' has past job equal to job')
    if dataset['JOB'][x]==dataset['CURRENT_JOB'][x]:
        print('ID: '+str(dataset['ID'][x])+' has current job equal to job')
```

Comment: There is no error but i'm not sure why there is no output. The code just run and that's it.